# How to add pkpass file to wallet without Preview from App?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, passkit

I have been adding **pkpass** file to the wallet by using PKAddPassesViewController since it presents the pass for preview and we have to add manually. 
But what i need is to add the pass to the wallet without preview.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible currently on iOS. User intervention is required to add the pass to wallet.

Comment: Is it possible to modify from app(not from the push notification)

Comment: Nope @Vinoth you can check if your pass exists in wallet already or not.